# Python: Find last letter in​ 'a_str'.Replace every occurence of this letter in​ 'a_str' with ‘@’. E.G 'a_str' = "Dog dog", output should be "Do@ do@"

Tags: python, string, data-manipulation

str_manip = input("Enter a sentence: ")

position = -1

new_character = "@"

temp = list(str_manip)

temp[position] = new_character

str_manip = "".join(temp)

print(str_manip)

Comment: Hi Likona, what's your question?

Comment: the above code: successfully changes the last 'character' of a string to "@". now if the last 'character' in a string was "s", I have to change every "s" on that same string to "@". How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace every instance of the last character of a string you can use Python's `replace()` method:

```py
string = 'good dog'
new_char = '@'
new_string = string.replace(string[-1], new_char)
print(new_string)

Output: '@ood do@'
```

Comment: @Likona, happy to hear it. Please mark my answer as correct using the little check mark below the up/down votes :)